# Can't Find IK in pose mode

Tags: inverse-kinematics

Can't Find IK

I am in pose mode I can use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> but that does not give what I want

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into *Bone Constraints*, not *Object Constraints*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Very Much